# Difficulty getting in touch with Stack Overflow customer support

Tags: support

5 days ago (08/24), I filed a ticket with customer support by clicking on the Contact Us link at the bottom of the site. I wrote to customer support regarding a somewhat urgent matter. I was told I would receive a response (usually) within 24 hours.

Days later, having received no response, I sent a follow up requesting an update on my issue.

Still no response.

I'm just wondering whether this is a one off thing or is Stack Overflow's customer support this poor in general. How can I have someone at Stack Overflow, Inc look into my ticket and respond in a timely manner?

Comment: Response times are always going to vary based on the nature of the request.  Some things can be handled in a few seconds of someone's time, and are thus typically answered very quickly.  Some requests may take days to resolve once someone sees the request and begins acting on it.  And lots in between.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the default auto-responder does say 24 hours, but that's not entirely true for all tickets. The 24 hours applies to Teams and Talent tickets, which have an SLA attached to them due to the nature of it being a paid service. We've actually never had any kind of SLA attached to community tickets before because their nature can make them much more difficult to handle in short amounts of time.

We've been *experimenting* with one, but it's currently set to a lot longer than the standard 24 hours that auto-reply gives you, and doesn't include weekends (because literally no one looks at community tickets over the weekend). We recently discovered that it's possible to change that auto-responder based on the type of ticket we received, so we'll likely change it to a longer time frame or just drop the time frame altogether for community tickets until we figure out what our SLA should be, if having one at all makes sense.

As an aside, priority is also an important factor here. Certain tickets are inherently more important and more dire than others. We generally *try* to handle tickets concerning users who are having trouble getting into their accounts at all before any others, regardless of when they came in, because that is a serious issue that drastically affects their ability to use our site versus someone who is confused about how a badge works, or complaining about an unexpected reputation change.

You contacted us about a clarification for a swag request you recently submitted, which is... honestly about the lowest priority ticket you can have. We love giving out swag, but that's also a fun thing we do for people that comes after pretty much everything else we need to process, because it's not necessary to do that in a hurry. We need to finish our dinner before we start in on the cake. I promise your swag won't get sent out before we've responded to that ticket.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I was a little apprehensive because I've heard the shipments can be delivered as soon as within 10 days that the form is filled out, and I needed to make sure you had all the information possible to deliver it without having it sent back, lost, or stolen. It may be low priority to you but it means a lot to me because it reflects the time I've invested into the site. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: @animuson Sorry for the off: also I have a long, looong unreacted ticket about my SEDE account, I absolutely understand that you really have also more important things to do, but it is around a half year old...